# Как избежать разрыва при печати идущих подряд DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, css, print

У меня на странице сейчас подряд идут ценники, которые располагаются в строку через flex-wrap. При печати я получаю разрыв ценника, а мне нужно, чтобы они переносились на следующую страницу.

Пробовал применять к ценникам
`page-break-inside: avoid;`, но это не помогает.

[image: Рвущиеся дивы]

Comment: Не претендую на правильность, но что если посчитать сколько в одну страницу влазит целый ценников, обернуть их в блок и поставить марджин-боттом на разницу?

Comment: Ценники не однотипны. Их размер может меняться

Comment: Кажется, с флексом работать не будет. Попробуйте переделать на блоки.

Comment: И с блоком не работает

Comment: Перед тем как написать коммент, я пробовал с `break-inside: avoid`, все работало если не ставить `display: flex`